# Rails 4 Project - Display Article Summary From External URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 4 project that lists hyperlinks that link to articles on other sites. What is the best way to pull in the summaries of these articles show I can show it in my project, specifically the image and the first 150 or so characters of the articles? Is there a gem for this? I think paperclip can pull in the image and if so, how can I pull in part of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use some API like this http://api.yandex.com/rca/